# Posting PDF file to SOLR via python

Tags: python, pdf, post, solr

I am having an issue of posting a PDF file to SOLR via python using urllib2. The code I am trying is as below

```
import urllib2
with open('key.pdf', 'rb') as data_file:
   my_data = data_file.read()
req = urllib2.Request(url='http:// localhost:8983/solr/update/pdf?commit=true',data=my_data)
req.add_header('Content-type', 'application/pdf')
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

I get an error HTTP 404 error code.

However I was able to successfully post using this command:

```
http:// localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal._id=doc2 -Dtype=application/pdf -jar post.jar key.pdf
```

Could you please let me know the mistake I am doing. For above command I have configured SOLR extract handler.

Further to this  made a change as below

```
import urllib2
with open('key.pdf', 'rb') as data_file:
my_data = data_file.read()
req = urllib2.Request(url='http ://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?commit=true',data=my_data)
req.add_header('Content-type', 'application/pdf')
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

I get a HTTP 400 error now and in SOLR log in can see error "Document is missing mandaotory uniquekey field: _id"

How Do I incorpoare _id to above python code.If so how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `literal.fieldname` to include `fieldname` to Solr  when using extracting handler.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler#Literals

[Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) can take a `params` dict like `{'commit': 'true', 'field':'this/ ?text may invalidate your url'}` and do the job of making it URL-safe.

Comment: Thanks Aithnyu. this has worked. req = urllib2.Request(url='http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?commit=true&literal._id=doc25',data=my_data)

Comment: If you find answers to your questions useful ,please accept them (click the check next to answer).